# Linkedin Marketing API March 31 queries update

Tags: curl, http-headers, linkedin-api, multipartform-data

Some may know, Linkedin Marketing API announced they will begin rejecting API calls not meeting new criteria starting March 31, 2021. So I started updating my service. However, there is such a problem. The sample CURL commands given in the documentation do not work. [Related announcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/query-tunneling-migration)

Have you encountered such a problem before? If I need to show you a few examples:

```
curl -X POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2 \
  -H 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=xyz;' \
  -H 'X-RestLi-Method: BATCH_PARTIAL_UPDATE' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' \
  -H 'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
  --data $'--xyz\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{"entities": {{"47770196": {"patch": {"$set": {"status": "ACTIVE"}}}}}}\r\n--xyz--'
```

Response:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Invalid tunneled request - Missing start boundary",
    "status": 400
}
```

The examples in which the GET requests mentioned in the documentation are converted to POST work fine, but the header used in post requests: `-H Content-Type: multipart / mixed; boundary = xyz;` causing the problem.

edit:

As Matteo said below, the problem was at the `\r\n` But, I'm using PHP CURL in my app. I'm not sure how can I translate `\r\n` to carriage return. This is a usage example:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    $jsonData = "
    --xyz
    Content-Type: application/json" 
    . json_encode($parameters, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
    . 
    "--xyz--";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $ch,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        [
        'Authorization Bearer $access_token',
        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=xyz;',
        'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0',
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'
    ]);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: can you post the request you are try to migrate? His [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/query-tunneling-migration#example-1) the case?

Comment: Hmm.. None of them working actually. The example above is one of them.. Have you tried? You can check it out from [here](https://reqbin.com/curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try translating every `\r\n` with a carriage return, as example:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2' \
  -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=xyz" \
  -H "X-RestLi-Method: BATCH_PARTIAL_UPDATE" \
  -H "X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0 " \
  --data $'--xyz\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
ids=List(123)
--xyz
Content-Type: application/json

{"entities": {{"123": {"patch": {"$set": {"status": "ACTIVE"}}}}}}
--xyz--'
```

[See here in action](https://reqbin.com/c-6mcsdiof)

For further information see [the specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) about how multipart work

PS: Is not the first time I've found [an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Contribute/issues/219) in the linkedin doc

**EDIT:**

PHP Sample code:

```
<?php

$ch = \curl_init();
$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2";
$parameters = [
    "entities" => [
        [
            [
                "47770196" => [
                    "patch" => [
                        "\$set" => [
                            "status" => "ACTIVE",
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
],
];

$jsonData = "
--xyz
Content-Type: application/json"
. json_encode($parameters, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
.
"--xyz--";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt(
$ch,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
[
'Authorization Bearer $access_token',
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=xyz;',
'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0',
'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

print_r($result);
print_r($error);


curl_close($ch);
```

with print:

```
>php -f src/ln.php
{"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}%
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is absolutely working. But I'm using PHP CURL in my app. But I'm not sure how to make it work. I edited my question. Can you check it out, please?

Comment: Sorry @MuratColyaran I can't replicate the issue with PHP: my code exit with the "Empty oauth2 access token" error

Comment: I solved when I remove space between double quote and `--xyz` like this:
`$jsonData = "--xyz`
It's working now. Thank you again @Matteo