# Linkedin Marketing API Can't Send Tunneled Requests

Tags: curl, linkedin-api, multipartform-data

Microsoft [announced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/query-tunneling-migration) a new tunneling request system for LinkedIn Marketing API system to replace the old request system that will be deprecated. However, I noticed that CREATE and UPDATE calls are not working in this new request system. The requests return with the answer I show below.

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 0,
"message": "Invalid tunneled request - Missing start boundary",
"status": 400
}
```

I had the opportunity to work with CURL requests before, but I have never worked with multipart. As I mentioned below, where do you think the boundary is faulty in a CURL request?

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/atsCandidates' \
-H 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=xyz' \
-H 'x-restli-method: batch_update' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer redacted' \
--data $'--xyz\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\nids[0].atsCandidateId=CAND123&ids[0].dataProvider=ATS&ids[0].integrationContext=urn:li:organization:1000&ids[1].atsCandidateId=CAND456&ids[1].dataProvider=ATS&ids[1].integrationContext=urn:li:organization:1000\r\n--xyz\r\n 
Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{
  "entities": {    "atsCandidateId=CAND123&dataProvider=ATS&integrationContext=urn:li:organization:1000": {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "line1": "31 Spooner St",
          "city": "Quahog",
          "geographicArea": "RI",
          "geographicAreaType": "STATE",
          "postalCode": "02802",
          "country": "us"
        }
      ],
      "atsCreatedAt": 1484864187000,
      "atsLastModifiedAt": 1484864187000,
      "currentCompanyName": "Pawtucket Patriot Brewery",
      "currentJobTitle": "Quality Assurance",
      "emailAddresses": [
        "foo@example.com"
      ],
      "externalProfileUrl": "https://example.com/p-griffin",
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Griffin",
      "middleInitial": "L",
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "number": "555-555-5555",
          "extension": "1234"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "Mr",
      "suffix": "Jr"
    },
    "atsCandidateId=CAND456&dataProvider=ATS&integrationContext=urn:li:organization:1000": {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "line1": "1000 W Maude Ave",
          "line2": "ATTN: Maude Flanders",
          "city": "Calgary",
          "geographicArea": "AB",
          "geographicAreaType": "PROVINCE",
          "postalCode": "T1X 0L3",
          "country": "ca"
        }
      ],
      "atsCreatedAt": 1484864187000,
      "atsLastModifiedAt": 1484864187000,
      "emailAddresses": [
        "foo@example.com"
      ],
      "externalProfileUrl": "https://example.com/m-flanders",
      "firstName": "Maude",
      "lastName": "Flanders",
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "number": "555-666-7777",
          "extension": "1234"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "Mrs"
    }
  }
}\r\n--xyz--'
```

Comment: Try adding the `'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0'` header to your request

Comment: Hi @Kulunce See if this answer could you help https://stackoverflow.com/a/66547540/2270041